# Actor's "remuneration" for a "job/gig/engagement"

Tags: word-choice

What's the correct term to refer to the money an actor earns as a result of performing on a movie/film? The contractual "engagement/fee/honorarium" for the service of acting.

Slang and official terms, please, if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with "payment"?

Comment: How can "the correct term" invite a list of slang?

Comment: There are a **lot** of possible answers here. In the USA, for instance, these are terms of art and contract law, for which one should consult [Actors' Equity](http://www.actorsequity.org/); for current slang, one should consult current actors.

Comment: @JohnLawler: you seem to be very knowledgeable in this field, care to share some terms from your "off the top of your head" list? Casting fee?

Comment: Per John Lawler, there are also layers of payments having to do with straight fees, percentages of gross, residuals, product tie-ins, ancillary benefits (getting to keep the costumes, which the IRS might consider income), etc., etc.

Comment: @bib: precisely! You are exactly on the right track! That's what I meant... Awesome. An answer with some terms may help me and the next person stumbling on this post...

Comment: I think this is Not Constructive. I've heard actors/musicians justify a "tacky" performance by saying *"It's their dime"* ("they" being the people directly paying the performer). By my reckoning, therefore, **dime** is just one more entry in a ridiculously long list of words that can be used with OP's intended meaning. There is no "right" answer.

Comment: All the protesting sounds like people just don't know an answer. But you could improve your question with some explanation. Why -isn't- 'payment' work? Do you know of some already? If so why do you think there are more? If not, why do you think there are any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer hinges on what you mean by "correct".

If you mean normal usage, then, as others point out, it is better to consult a general reference on slang words. This may yield interesting geographic or temporal differences in usage. What did minstrels work for if not a dime?

However, if you mean the official term, then those terms that refer to the delivery of any service on agreed-upon terms, such as payment, remuneration, or even fee, should apply. As an aside, these categories are not mutually exclusive because a slang word can become official by agreement.

Answer (score -2):

Because *Art* is created/performed for so many different reasons, I think that the words for the 'engagement' and 'compensation' do not have much common-agreement.

If you seek for the best word, look to the context of how the artistic work was solicited, its duration, and how arrangements for compensation were made.  The patterns will be similar to the patterns of other employment, and words from other other situations of work/labor will probably feel the most correct in this context.